# how to change php variable name in a loop?

Tags: php, variables, loops, for-loop

Lets say I have a variable called $file and the for loop: `for($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++) {}`

For each iteration of the for loop, the `$i` value will be appended to the `$file` variable name so after the for loop ends, I should have five variables: `$file1`, `$file2`, `$file3`, `$file4`, and `$file5`.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Using an (associative) array as a portable namespace is almost always a better solution.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use [${'varname'} syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
for($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    ${'file' . $i} = $i;
}
```

However, it's often better to use arrays instead of this.

Comment: @Yuri Thank you so much!  Even in 2014 your answer is helping people!

Comment: Arrays for what I am doing won't help, I am making a file line by line so I have `$line01="foo"`....`$line55="bar"` so doing this variable variable method seems to make the most sense for me, unless there is a better way in creating the line by lines?   So. how do I had the 0 padding on 01-09 as well?  I suppose an if statement within the for loop but is there a better way?

Answer (score 15):

There **is** a way to do this:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    ${'file'.$i} = ...;
}
```

But it is a **bad idea** to do this. Why is it a bad idea? Because this is what **arrays** are meant for. Do this instead:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $file[$i] = ...;
}
```

(NB. It is the usual convention to start array keys at 0 rather than 1, but you do not have to do so.)

Answer (score 4):

it is possible to do what you want, but creating variables on the fly seems an unusual way to solve a problem like this (i could be wrong)

I would suggest storing the filenames in an array, that way you can easily iterate over the files later on, or add an extra file and not have to change any hardcoded variable names

```
    $myfiles = array();

    for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
       $myfiles["file$i"] = "value set in loop";
    }

    //if you want to use the values later
    $file5_value = $myfiles["file5"];

    //if you want to loop through them all
    foreach ($myfiles as $key => $val) {
      echo "$key -> $val\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an array as well. It doesn't have the same exact affect, but it is generally what I see used in these situations.

```
for($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $file[$i] = $i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See PHP's manual on [Variable Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```
$var_name = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
  $var_name = 'file' . $i;

  // reference $$var_name now.
  $$var_name = 'foo';
}

var_dump($file1);
var_dump($file2);
var_dump($file3);
var_dump($file4);
var_dump($file5);
```

**[demo](http://www.ideone.com/CEXKx)**