# PHP - How Can I Create Variable Names Within a Loop?

Tags: php, variables

My goal is to have a loop where variable names are created.  Such as:

`$variable1`
`$variable2`
`$variable3`

and assigned values within the loop.  For instance, a `for loop` from 1 to 7 produces the variables `$variable1, $variable2, $variable3,` .etc, each with the value of the iterator.

Comment: Use an array...

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change php variable name in a loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234864/how-to-change-php-variable-name-in-a-loop)

Comment: If you post the context of your actual problem, we may be able to provide alternative solutions which don't require this functionality and will lead to cleaner code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change php variable name in a loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234864/how-to-change-php-variable-name-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There are several ways. One is via a string and a double `$`, but I don't like this method. A programmer could easily remove the double `$` (seeing it as a typeo).

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 7; $i++) {
     $name = "variable{$i}";
     $$name = "foo";
}
```

The best approach is the explicit statement.

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 7; $i++) {
     ${"variable$i"} = "foo";
}
```

With the explicit inline string there is no doubt about the intent of what you're doing. Another PHP programmer will not alter the code by mistake.

Comment: Actually, for some reason, my first solution isn't working. Tried on multiple servers: http://ideone.com/rvJnj7. I've deleted my post.

Comment: @Nile I was about to comment on it: it *looks* like it would work, but it doesn't http://codepad.org/L6XYoGNM - PHP sees `$variable{$i}` as an attempt to index either an array element or a byte of a string in the variable `$variable`, just like `$variable[$i]` would be; given an unset value, it prefers an array. So you are actually initialising an indexed array here, not a set of named variables as requested.

Answer (score 17):

You should use an array for this:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {
  $variable[$i] = $i;
}
```

**Edit:** to clarify, you should use an array because there's no code (to my knowledge) which will accept $variable1 but not $variable[1]. Dynamically generating variable names is all kinds of wrong.

Comment: @Kolink they are PHP's version of other languages inflection.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini I can't find any programming meanings of "inflection"; did you mean "reflection"? And if so, what does dynamically naming variables have to do with reflection (which, incidentally, PHP does support)?

Comment: @IMSoP `inflection` means to modify an object at run-time from it's original meaning. PHP is a dynamic language and was designed to do this kind of thing. While it's not a good idea it's also not a good idea to program in PHP ;)

Comment: +1 this is totally the right thing to do, but doesn't solve the OP's problem. Sadly, this is the life of a programmer.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini OK, I hadn't heard that definition. Not sure how it applies here, though, as we're not changing the meaning of a variable, we're naming variables at runtime, something with extremely limited uses.

Comment: @IMSoP the word `inflection` is an ambiguous term that means to change an object after it's been defined/declared/created. It depends upon the programming language. Renaming a variable at runtime is kind of the same thing. Just as in JavaScript where you can add functions to an object at runtime or rename those functions. These are just features of language. Why they did it this way? I have no idea, but the more flexible the easier to abuse.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini Renaming a variable is not at all the same as changing one of its properties, as a variable name is not a property of the value it points at. Nor are we "renaming" anything here, just creating things with names that are decided at run-time rather than compile-time. Dynamically adding *properties* to an *object* is a slightly different case, with slightly more uses, although a hash/array is still generally a wiser choice. (In JS, the distinction is moot, because all variables except one "root" object are technically properties of some other object.)

Comment: @MathewFoscarini I'm also still drawing a blank on "inflection" as a programming term. Neither FOLDOC nor Wikipedia appears to have heard of it, and the only programming-related results Google gives me are for Ruby on Rails (and similar ORMs) handling inflected singular and plural nouns, or metaphorical and literal uses of the mathematical term "inflection point". Given your generic anti-PHP snark, I'm beginning to think you may have just been trolling.

Answer (score 5):

Just to expand on what others have said about why this is a technique best avoided: variable names exist solely for use by the programmer; they have no relationships or properties according to the language's runtime. As such, a collection of related variables should be put into a variable representing some appropriate container - in the case of PHP, its incredibly flexible "array" type.

Whenever the issue of dynamically named variables is raised, it is usually because somebody thinks it is a solution to a particular problem, but it generally leads to more problems than it solves - for instance, once part of a program starts dynamically naming variables, everywhere that wants to use those variables now *also* has to dynamically name them; finding out which items are actually set becomes unnecessarily complex, and so on.

There are a very few contexts where variable-variables are useful, for certain kinds of debugging and meta-programming, for example, but like [`goto`](http://php.net/goto), their presence in the language should not mean you don't try every other possible solution first.

999 times out of 1000, though, if you find yourself wondering how to dynamically create variable names, you should reframe the question: what are you *actually* trying to achieve, and what is the best solution to that problem. If some existing / 3rd-party code has been built using this pattern (and presumably also global variables), it may be best to patch or wrap it rather than propogating the mis-design into your own code. (Admittedly, a wrapper will still need to know how to declare the dynamic variables.)

Answer (score 1):

If you had an associative array i'ld prefer using the `extract()` method. Check it out [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

for example

```
<?php

/* Suppose that $var_array is an array*/

$var_array = array("color" => "blue",
               "size"  => "medium",
               "shape" => "sphere");
extract($var_array, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, "wddx");

echo "$color, $size, $shape";

?>
```

the above code would output,
`blue, large, sphere, medium`

Answer (score 0):

In case any one wants to do this through an object:

```
<?php 
        $x = 1;
        while($x <= 4){
        echo $q->{"a$x"}; 
        $x++;
?>
```

Answer (score -16):

Thats no possible since variable cannot be create in run time