# How to differentiate each instance of the same test

Tags: php, codeception

#### What am I trying to achieve?

I made a test which logs into a web application, completes an exam and submits it.
Since I'm simulating multiple users doing the exam to test how many the server can handle, I need a way to tell each instance of my test to pick a different user to log in.

For now I'm trying to store the credentials in a text file, and before the test is executed make it to take a pair of credentials from the file and delete that line, but I'm not sure if this is the most realiable approach.

This is the code I made (inside the test itself):

```
public function _before(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $file = fopen("trainees.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
        flock($file, LOCK_EX);
        $credentials = fgets($file);
        $trainee = $credentials;
        $credentials = '';
        fwrite($file, $credentials);

        flock($file, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($file);

        return $trainee;
    }
// test
    public function loginSuccessfully(AcceptanceTester $I,$trainee)
    { 

        $credentials = explode(':',$trainee,2);

    
        $I->amOnPage('');
        $I->wait(2.5);
        $I->fillField('username',$credentials[0]);
        $I->wait(1);
        $I->fillField('password',$credentials[1]);
        $I->wait($speed[0]);
        $I->click('Login');
    }
```

Running this is giving me this error:

```
[PHPUnit\Framework\Exception] explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given
```

This is the txt file where I store the credentials:

```
008C108:8706405
008C408:1776723
008B108:9315051
```

This is my RoboFile:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

class RoboFile extends \Robo\Tasks
{
    use \Codeception\Task\MergeReports;
    use \Codeception\Task\SplitTestsByGroups;

    public function parallelSplitTests()
    {
        // Split your tests by files
        $this->taskSplitTestFilesByGroups(5)
            ->projectRoot('.')
            ->testsFrom('tests/acceptance')
            ->groupsTo('tests/_data/paracept_')
            ->run();
    }

    public function parallelRun()
    {
        $parallel = $this->taskParallelExec();

            for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {

                $parallel->process(
                $this->taskCodecept() // use built-in Codecept task
                    ->suite('acceptance') // run acceptance tests
                    ->group("paracept_$i") // for all paracept_* groups
                    ->xml("tests/_log/result_$i.xml") // save XML results
                );
            }

    return $parallel->run();
    }

    public function parallelMergeResults()
    {
          $merge = $this->taskMergeXmlReports();
        for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
            $merge->from("tests/_output/result_paracept_$i.xml");
        }
        $merge->into("tests/_output/result_paracept.xml")->run();
    }
}
```

This was just my idea but I don't know if this is the best approach.

Comment: Make it generic with literal eval command put counter in the name of every new username instance.

Comment: @NikolaLukic I'm sorry, could you explain a little what do you mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135192/php-how-can-i-create-variable-names-within-a-loop

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks for the reply @NikolaLukic

Comment: Codeception is not a load testing tool, use JMeter or Gattling or some other tool more appropriate for this job.